# Set RGB background-color of an Excel cell with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

i am trying copy cells from one row to the one below. To copy the comments and cellvalues works fine. Now if I set a background-color in Excel and want to just copy it to the new cell, it doesn't work. Either there is just no color after copying or the background is black.
I tried that:

```
style2.setFillBackgroundColor(cell_master_alt.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor());
style2.setFillForegroundColor(cell_master_alt.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor());

style2.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);    or
style2.setFillPattern(cell_master_alt.getCellStyle().getFillPattern());

cell_master_neu.setCellStyle(style2);
```

After a few hours without any progress, I looked into the foreground- and background-color of the cell I want to copy. There I found RGB values. Now I want to make a new Cellstyle with that values, but that doesn't work as well.
First I try this:

```
style_new.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128,128,128)));
```

but there is an error message:

```
The method setFillForegroundColor(short) in the type CellStyle is not applicable for the arguments (XSSFColor)
```

What is wrong with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apache POI cell styles can be applied to multiple cells due to the way Excel stores them in the binary format, thus it should suffice to just apply the cell style from one cell onto the other without any copying:

```
cell_master_neu.setCellStyle(cell_master_alt.getCellStyle());
```

Comment: Way too easy to think of...
Thank you